# GatsbyJS/Netlify form issues

Tags: reactjs, forms, gatsby, netlify

I have already researched this extensively and found no real answer thus far -- maybe this is a simple formatting error I'm making, but it's driving me nuts.

Trying to get my Gatsby site to be able to receive inquiries from contact form which will route to my email via Netlify form submission notification. Upon clicking "send message" user should be routed to the "/success" page. I'm on gatsby 2.4.8.

Here is my code from index.js which houses the contact form ( gatsby-starter-strata template).

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="8u 12u$(small)">
    <form
      name="contact"
      method="POST"
      action="/success"
      data-netlify="true"
      data-netlify-honeypot="bot-field"
    >
      <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
      <div className="row uniform 50%">
        <div className="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div className="6u 12u$(xsmall)">
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div className="12u">
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id="message"
            placeholder="Message"
            rows="4"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ul className="actions">
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the routing working? Do you see a request being sent in the Network tab of the Developer Tools? Can you see in Netlify if you have gotten any submitted forms?

Comment: I need to do more research on the gatsby routing as this is a SPA. This is the message I received when I went to Network tab: 

"The resource https://user.com/static/d/520/path---offline-plugin-app-shell-fallback-a-30-c5a-NZuapzHg3X9TaN1iIixfv1W23E.json was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally."

Netlify has not received any submitted forms.

Comment: submit input is outside the form

Comment: **facepalm**
Thank you.